# Implementation of scheduling algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, scheduling

I have an assignment where I need to develop a simulation of a process scheduler. I got most of it setup but I am stuck at figuring out the logic to actually schedule the processes. Right now I have a struct created that holds processes with their pid, cycle count and memory requirement. And I have used a vector to hold all the 100 processes so I can sort them if I want to and remove processes as I schedule them.

For the 5 processors I just created an int array but I am guessing the processors should have cycle count and memory limits? In that case another struct maybe?

And how would I actually assign processes to these 5 processors? Can someone help me figure that out? I just need to implement a simple FCFS algorithm.

```
void init_process_list(vector<process> &p_list) {

    generator generate; // Random number generator class
    process p;

    for(int i = 0; i < process_count; i++) {
        p.process_id = i;
        p.cpu_cycles = generate.rand_num_between(cycle_lbound, cycle_ubound);
        p.mem_footprint = generate.rand_num_between(mem_lbound, mem_ubound);
        p_list.push_back(p);
    }

}

// Initialize processor array
void init_processor_list(int *processor_list) {

    for(int i = 0; i < processor_count; i++)
        processor_list[i] = 0;

}

void schedule_processes(vector<process> &p_list, int *processor) {

}

int main() {

    vector<process> process_list;
    int cpu[processor_count];

    init_process_list(process_list);
    init_processor_list(cpu);

    schedule_processes(process_list, cpu);

}
```

Comment: From a quick look at your assignment, they probably want you to implement [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm)

Comment: @Mints97 I actually need to implement a simple FCFS algorithm

Comment: Well, it sounds like you're on the right track - done the easy bit, know to Google FCFS for some example pseudo or actual code - why are you here?  We help people who're stuck, not paused....

Comment: How does FCFS count as developing an algorithm to minimize total time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you understand below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<thread>
#include <future>

int global_processorID =0;
int global_processID   =0;

struct Process
{
    int cycles;
    int memory;
    int pid;
    Process()
    {
        pid = global_processID++;
        cycles = rand()%1000;
        memory = rand()%100;
    }
};

class Processor
{
public:
    Processor():processing(false)
    {

        this->processorID = global_processorID++;
    }
    bool processsing()
    {
        return processing;
    }
    void process(Process& process)
    {
        processing= true;

        std::async(std::launch::async,[&]
        {
            std::cout<<"Processor ID: "<<this->processorID<<" ,started Processing for cycles"<<process.cycles<<" ,process id :"<<process.pid<<std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(process.cycles*10));
            std::cout<<"Done Processing: "<<process.pid<<std::endl;
            processing=false;
        });
    }
    int processorID;
private:
    bool processing; 
};
class scheduler
{
public:

    void addPrcessor(Processor& aprocessor)
    {
        processor.push_back(&aprocessor);
    }

    void prcess(Process& process)
    {
        getNextAvilableProcessor()->process(process);
    }
    Processor* getNextAvilableProcessor()
    {
        for(auto& a : processor)
        {
            if(!a->processsing())
                return a;
        }
        std::cout<<"All processors are busy, Waiting for next avilable processor\n";
        while(true)
        {
            for(auto& a : processor)
            {
                if(!a->processsing())
                    return a;
            }
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<Processor*> processor;

};

int main()
{

int i =257;
int*ptr = &i;
    std::vector<Process> processes(100);
    scheduler scheduler;
    Processor one;
    Processor two;
    Processor three;
    Processor four;
    scheduler.addPrcessor(one);
    scheduler.addPrcessor(two);
    scheduler.addPrcessor(three);
    scheduler.addPrcessor(four);

    for(auto& process : processes)
    {
        scheduler.prcess(process);
    };


}
```

Comment: hmm.. could be because of C++ 11, Adjust code as per your compiler

Comment: @Satbir do you have an implementation of this without using O.O.P? really difficult to understand the logic.

Comment: @Mohsin I will try and will give you a link soon. Thx

Answer (score 0):

It should be described in [Windows Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735648735). I have read [a very similar book](http://www.jadro-windows.cz/) (not available in English) where the algorithm of process scheduling was described.

Comment: corrections suggested: delete `in` before *described*, add `a` before *very similar book*